# ¿Por que no coloca los bordes en rojo a los select como los hace con los input? utilizando el plugin formValidation.io

Tags: formularios, select2

Estoy utilizando el plugin `select2` pero asi le quite la libreria tampoco me tilda los select.

Acá mi formulario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá uno mas simple:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá el código HTML:

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="form-crear" class="form_con_select2">
<div class="modal-body"> 
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="crear_nombre" class="control-label col-sm-2">Nombre: </label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="crear_nombre" name="crear_nombre">
  </div>
 </div> 
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="crear_descripcion" class="control-label col-sm-2">Descripción: </label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="crear_descripcion" name="crear_descripcion">
  </div> 
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="crear_marca" class="control-label col-sm-2">Marca:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8 selectContainer">
   <select id="crear_marca" name="crear_marca" style="width: 100%;">
    @foreach($marcas as $marca) 
     <option value="{{$marca->id}}">{{$marca->nombre}}</option>
    @endforeach
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cerrar 
 </button>
 <button type="button" id="Guardar" name="Guardar" class="btn btn-primary">
  <span class="fa fa-save"> Guardar</span>
 </button>
</div>
</form>
```

Acá el script:

```html
$('#form-crear').formValidation({
 framework: 'bootstrap',
 excluded: ':disabled',
 button: {
  selector: '#Guardar',
  disabled: 'disabled'
 },
 icon: {
  valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
  invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign',
  validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
 },
 fields: {
  crear_nombre: {
   validators: {
    notEmpty: {
     message: 'Campo requerido'
    },
    stringLength: {
     min: 5,
     max: 50,
     message: 'Introduzca un valor entre 5 a 50 caracteres de largo'
    },
    regexp: {
     regexp: /^[a-zA-Zá-úÁ-Ú ñÑ]+$/,
     message: 'Solo se permite letras'
    },
    remote: {
     message: 'Ya esta registrado',
     url: "personas/comprobacion",  
     type: "post",
      global: false,
     data: {
      valor: 'crear'
     },
     async: true
    }
   }
  },
  crear_descripcion: {
   validators: {
    notEmpty: {
     message: 'Campo requerido'
    },
    stringLength: {
     min: 5,
     max: 50,
     message: 'Introduzca un valor entre 5 a 50 caracteres de largo'
    },
    regexp: {
     regexp: /^[a-zA-Zá-úÁ-Ú ñÑ]+$/,
     message: 'Solo se permite letras'
    }
   }
  },
  crear_marca: {
   validators: {
    notEmpty: {
     message: 'Campo requerido'
    }
   }
  }
 }
})
.on('err.form.fv', function(e, data) {
})
.on('success.form.fv', function(e) {
});
```

y aca un ejemplo de la web del plugin: [enlace](http://formvalidation.io/examples/select2/)

Answer (score 1):

Mirando el ejemplo de la web del plugin, veo que te falta ponerle la clase "select2-select" al *select*. Pudiera ser que esta librería inicialice los *select* buscando por esa clase en tu HTML.

```
<select id="crear_marca" name="crear_marca" class="select2-select" style="width: 100%;">
    @foreach($marcas as $marca) 
        <option value="{{$marca->id}}">{{$marca->nombre}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: nada mano, igual